# Assume $A$ and $B$sets, show that $\{\{x\} \times B | x \in A\}$ is a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

*Note: I'm using ZFC set theory. Axioms can be found [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Zermelo-FraenkelAxioms.html)*

I know that my question is very simple, but I still cannot grasp something about the subset axiom (so I guess my question is a bit  broader than I presented).

That's the proof I designed (wrong: needs to be corrected):

1. Consider the set $A \times B = \{ <q,z> | q \in A \land z \in B \}$
2. Use a subset axiom: $\forall A, B. \exists C. \forall<q,z> (<q,z> \in C \iff \exists x \in A : q=x \land z \in B)$ *Note: I set $q=x$ because $q \in \{x\} \iff q=x$*.
3. That set is what we were looking for because, by definition $\{\{x\} \times B | x \in A\} = \{t = <r,s> | (\exists x \in A : r \in x) \land (s \in B)\} $

Does it work? 
The broader problem (which avoids me accepting this proof) is that I cannot understand when, using the subset axiom, I make this **mistake**:
For a subset axiom, the set B exists:

$\exists B \forall x(x \in B \iff x=x)$

But that set does not exist: it's a class in the ZFC set theory... I was wondering if I made that mistake here and, more generally, how to avoid it.

A second question is: the former problem was taken from an exercise which tells me to prove also that, given $A,B,C$ as above, $A \times B = \bigcup C$. I've skectched a proof, but I'm not able to complete it. could you give me some hints?

Proof:

1. $W = \bigcup C = \bigcup \{\{x\} \times B | x \in A\} = \{<q,z> | \exists x \in A: q=x \land z\in B\}$
2. $Y = A \times B = \{<q',z'> | q' \in A \land z \in B\}$ Because $Y$ chooses any member of $A$ and $W$ needs an element of $A$ to "work", I can always set $q' = \{x\}$ to make Y a subset of W. I cannot prove the contrary.

Thanks a lot and sorry for the triviality of my question.

Comment: "But that set does not obviously exist."  Yes, it does.  If $\forall x(x \in B \iff x= x)$ means that $B$ is the universal set that contains all all elements.  It most certainly does exist

Comment: $\{\{x\} \times B | x \in A\} = \{t = <r,s> | \exists x \in A : r \in x\}$ should be $\{\{x\} \times B | x \in A\} = \{t = <r,s> | (\exists x \in A : r =x )\land ( s \in B)\}$

Comment: The subset axiom isn't about showing a set exists. It's about showing that a subset exists and is a subset.

Comment: $\{\{x\} \times B | x \in A\} = \{t = <r,s> | \exists x \in A : r \in x\}$.  Actually this is not true.  $\{x\} \times B$ is not a pair.  It is a set.  If $A=\{1,2,3\}$ and $B = \{a,b,c\}$ then $A\times B=\{<1,a>,<1,b>,....,<3,b>,<3,c>$ is a set with nine eleents; each element a pair.  But $\{\{x\}\times B|x\in A\} = \{\{1\}\times B, \{2\}\times B,\{3\}\times B\} = \{\{<1,a>,<1,b>,<1,2>\},\{<2,a>,<2,b>,<2,c>\},\{<3,a>,<3,b>,<3,c>\}$.  This is a set with three elements; each element a set of three pairs.

Comment: I'm a bit confused with "show something is a set".  Are you in a class that has definitions and axioms for the existance of sets?  If so please list what the axioms actually are.  They are not universally known.

Comment: @fleablood, I am working with ZFC set theory. I've just updated the question to point that out. The set of all sets does not exist as a set, but rather as a class. Your remarks made me understand that the proof is wrong, so I'll review it and update the existing one.

Comment: So in other words, according to axioms, such and such well-defined "set" has to be proven to conform with the axioms.  Fair enough.  I think you did a valiant effort with the subset axiom but I think it doesn't quite match the sets actual definition.  Which is not what it appears on first blush.

Answer (score 0):

This set $\mathcal{A} = \{\{x\} \times B: x \in A\}$ is just a special subset of $\mathscr{P}(A \times B)$. Write down the defining formula.

E.g.: $p \in \mathcal{A}$ iff ($\exists x \in A: (q \in p) \leftrightarrow (\exists b \in B: q = \langle x,p\rangle)$, or something similar.

And a lemma (you probably know it) says that $A \times B$ is a set if $A$ and $B$ are. Then the powerset and comprehension axiom do the rest..

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I forgot to point out that I was using ZFC. As far as I've understood, the comprehension axiom was refused in that theory. I'd have liked to point that out in the tags, but I haven't found a proper tag to do that :-(

Comment: I tried to design another formula, following your idea that my set is a subset of $\mathscr{P}(A\times B)$: $\forall A,B \exists \mathcal{A} : \forall z (z \in \mathcal{A} \iff z \in \mathcal{P}(A \times B) \land (\forall b \in B \exists x \in A : q \in z \iff q=<x,b>))$. As I'm pretty new to the subject, I was wondering whether it works or not.

Comment: @LuxGiammi Comprehension: "if $A$ is a set and $\phi$ is a fomula, then $\{x \in A: \phi(x)\}$ is a set too", is one of the fundamental axioms of ZFC. So it was not "refused" at all. Only Frege's (unbounded) variant that $\{x: \phi(x)\}$ always is a set, was a problem, as Russell pointed out.

Comment: So the comprehension axiom is what here (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Zermelo-FraenkelAxioms.html) is called "Subsets axiom", right? My statement about the refusal of that axiom was because a book called "the comprehension axiom" the Frege's variant, while calling "the subset axiom" the version that has $x \in A$ as a prerequisite.

Comment: @LuxGiammi indeed, the subset axiom (as it’s called there) is the one I learned as comprehension axiom (which they mention as another name for it).

Comment: "This set A={{x}×B:x∈A} is just a special subset of P(A×B)."  I don't think tht is true.  The elements of FancyA are sets, not ordered pairs.

Comment: @fleablood that’s what I said; they’re elements of a power set.

Comment: Oops.  Reading comprehension and coffee lack and...  stupidly I read "of" to mean "from".  I.e a subset of AxB that is an element of P (AxB).  Which... really wasn't there at all.  Sorry.

Comment: I'm being a little dense today.  Is Axiom 9, the axiom of choice, an axiom that allows $A\times B$ to exist and be a set?

Comment: @fleablood AC is not needed for a product of two sets. Just axiom of pairs, powerset and comprehension.